# Change driver focus between different page in single window in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am a beginner in Selenium Automation, and stuck with a situation, where, if I open a page xyz.com, and login, then there are some text box and dropdown and buttons to be clicked but the thing is, after the driver get to that page, I can see those elements, and can get the ID and necessary tags, but these whole page consist of 3 different (.do) page.

For example:
 1. main page is abc.do
 2. left panel is mno.do
 3. center is xyz.do
[Image of Inspect Element in IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYF1Y.png)
and my elements exists in xyz.do, and links in mno.do.

I am using eclipse to code, Selenium 3.1, IE 11

How can I switch between them so that my driver can find the elements, write now its showing element cannot be found, and when I pulled the source code its providing of only first .do page.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to post some of the relevant HTML. Enough that we can see the issue for ourselves. You also need to post your current code attempt and explain how you are trying to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the page is using frames or iframes, but because you do not provide a URL, it's only a guess.

So, to switch a frame/iframe, simply use the `switchTo` method:

```
driver.switchTo().frame0); // Frame by number
driver.switchTo().frame("iframe1"); // Frame by selector
```

After that call, you switch into the "context" of that page/frame/iframe.

Comment: Thanks, on checking the DOM I found that there are dynamic nested Iframe created, using Index of frame to switch helped.